# Difficulty Updating String With a TextField in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I am currently having trouble modifying a String value using a TextField. Here is my (simplified) code so far:

```
class GradeItem: ObservableObject {

    @Published var name: String
    @Published var scoredPoints: Double
    @Published var totalPoints: Double
    let isUserCreated: Bool

    init(name: String, scoredPoints: Double, totalPoints: Double, isUserCreated: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.scoredPoints = scoredPoints
        self.totalPoints = totalPoints
        self.isUserCreated = isUserCreated
    }
}

var courses: [Course] {
    // initialization code...
}

struct GradeCalculatorView: View {

    @State var selectedCourseIndex: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // allows user to select a course:
            ForEach(0 ..< courses.count) { i in
                Button(action: {
                    self.selectedCourseIndex = i
                }, label: {
                    Text(courses[i].name)
                })
            }
            CourseView(course: courses[selectedCourseIndex])
        }
    }
}

struct CourseView: View {

    @ObservedObject var course: Course   // passed in from GradeCalculatorView

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(course.name)
            ForEach(course.categories, id: \.name) { category in
                GradeCategoryView(category: category)
            }
        }.padding(.leading).frame(alignment: .leading)
    }
}

struct GradeCategoryView: View {

    @ObservedObject var category: GradeCategory   // passed in from CourseView

    var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading) {

            HStack {
                Text(category.name)
                Spacer()
            }

            ForEach(category.items, id:\.name) { item in
                GradeItemRow(item: item)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct GradeItemRow: View {

    @ObservedObject var item: GradeItem   // passed in from GradeCategoryView

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Item Name", text: $item.name)
    }
}
```

I cannot seem to modify the GradeItem object's name using the TextField. When the TextField is edited, its text changes temporarily. However, when the GradeItemRow View is reloaded, it displays the GradeItem object's original name, rather than its updated name.

Would somebody please be able to help?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE: As per your requests, I have added more context to this sample code.

I know that this does not work, as when I attempt to modify a GradeItem's name with a TextField, it changes temporarily. However, when I select a different course and then the course I was initially on, the TextField displays the unmodified name value.

Comment: @Druv, on its own, your example works for me.  Are you using GradeItemRow in a ListView?  Also, what do you mean, when it is reloaded?  If you could, please post the snippet where  you are actually using GradeItemView.  There isn't enough information here.

Comment: concur with @kid_x the example works. You need to provide more context.

Comment: @kid_x  I very much appreciate the quick response! I have now included more context (but I have removed some code that is irrelevant to the data I want to modify, for the sake of cleanliness). Will this work for you?

Comment: @workingdog   ^^^

Answer (score 0):

The following test works.

```
class GradeItem: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var scoredPoints: Double
    @Published var totalPoints: Double
    let isUserCreated: Bool
    
    init(name: String, scoredPoints: Double, totalPoints: Double, isUserCreated: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.scoredPoints = scoredPoints
        self.totalPoints = totalPoints
        self.isUserCreated = isUserCreated
    }
    
    init() {
        self.name = "gradeItem" + UUID().uuidString
        self.scoredPoints = 0.0
        self.totalPoints = 0.0
        self.isUserCreated = false
    }
}

class Course: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var categories: [GradeCategory]
    init(name: String, categories: [GradeCategory]) {
        self.name = name
        self.categories = categories
    }
    init() {
        self.name = "course_" + UUID().uuidString
        self.categories = [GradeCategory]()
        self.categories.append(GradeCategory())
    }
}

class GradeCategory: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var items: [GradeItem]
    init(name: String, items: [GradeItem]) {
        self.name = name
        self.items = items
    }
    init() {
        self.name = "category_" + UUID().uuidString
        self.items = [GradeItem]()
        self.items.append(GradeItem())
    }
}

struct GradeItemRow: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: GradeItem   // passed in from GradeCategoryView
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Item Name", text: $item.name).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    }
}

struct GradeCategoryView: View {
    @ObservedObject var category: GradeCategory   // passed in from CourseView
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text(category.name)
                Spacer()
            }
            ForEach(category.items, id: \.name) { item in
                GradeItemRow(item: item)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CourseView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @ObservedObject var course: Course   // passed in from ContentView
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Button(action: {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Text("done")
            })
            Spacer()
            Text(course.name)
            ForEach(course.categories, id: \.name) { category in
                GradeCategoryView(category: category)
            }
            Spacer()
        }.padding(.leading).frame(alignment: .leading)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var courses: [Course] = [Course(), Course()]
    @State var selectedCourseIndex: Int = 0
    @State var showCourse = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0 ..< courses.count) { i in
                Button(action: {
                    self.selectedCourseIndex = i
                    self.showCourse = true
                }, label: {
                    Text(self.courses[i].name)
                })
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showCourse) {
            CourseView(course: self.courses[self.selectedCourseIndex])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped! But just wondering, what was the issue in what I originally did? I am rather new to Swift coming from Java so I am a little uncertain about how data outside of classes is handled

Comment: It is hard to tell exactly what was the issue, since all the info is not present.
By and large you were on the right track. Glad the answer helped.